# my code only ever out puts "You win, rock beats scissors."

Tags: javascript, web

This is the code, now matter what I input as the input parameter in the play function, it alwats returns "You win, rock beats scissors."

```
    function computerPlay() {
        switch(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1) {
            case 1:
                return "rock";
                break;
            case 2:
                return "paper";
                break;
            case 3:
                return "scissors";
                break;
            default:
                return "error1";
                break;
        }
        
    }
    let playerInput;
    function startPlay() {
        playerInput = prompt("Rock, paper, or scissors?");
        play(playerInput, computerPlay());
    }
    function play(a,b) {
        if(((a = "rock") && (b = "scissors")) || ((a = "paper") && (b = "rock")) || ((a = "scissors") && (b = "paper"))) {
            alert(`You win, ${a} beats ${b}!`);
        }else if(((a = "rock") && (b = "paper")) || ((a = "paper") && (b = "scissors")) || ((a = "scissors") && (b = "rock"))) {
            alert(`You lose, ${b} beats ${a}`);
        }else if(a == b) {
            alert("It's a tie.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use == to compare, not = since that assigns

Answer (score 3):

```
((a = "rock") && (b = "scissors")) 
|| ((a = "paper") && (b = "rock")) 
|| ((a = "scissors") && (b = "paper"))
```

These aren't comparisons. You need double equality signs: `a == "rock"`. A single `=` is an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I fixed your script for you:

```js
function computerPlay() {
    switch (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1) {
        case 1:
            return "rock";
            break;
        case 2:
            return "paper";
            break;
        case 3:
            return "scissors";
            break;
        default:
            return "error1";
            break;
    }

}

let playerInput;
function startPlay() {
    playerInput = prompt("Rock, paper, or scissors?");
    play(playerInput, computerPlay());
}

function play(a, b) {
    if (((a == "rock") && (b == "scissors")) || ((a == "paper") && (b == "rock")) || ((a == "scissors") && (b == "paper"))) {
        alert(`You win, ${a} beats ${b}!`);
    } else if (((a == "rock") && (b == "paper")) || ((a == "paper") && (b == "scissors")) || ((a == "scissors") && (b == "rock"))) {
        alert(`You lose, ${b} beats ${a}`);
    } else if (a == b) {
        alert("It's a tie.");
    }
}
```

You simply forgot to compare your variable correctly. Using `=` assigns a value to a variable, and `==` compares a value with a variable.

For example, this sets the value of the variable:

```js
var myVariable = "Hello World!";
```

And this compares the variable value with a string:

```js
if (myVariable == "Hello World!") {
    console.log("Hello!");
} else {
    console.log("Goodbye!");
}
```

Check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) for more comparison and logical operators.